# Center a button between two others in OnsenUI

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center, onsen-ui2

How do I center a button between two other buttons in a toolbar?

Here's my code and resulting screenshot

```
<div id="toptoolbar">
  <button class="toolbar-button">
    <i class="fa fa-comments" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>

  <button class="toolbar-button">
    My title
    <!-- text-purple center-block doesn't work -->
  </button>

  <button class="toolbar-button pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm using OnsenUI (and will be using VUE with it) so is there a class I can simply add from bootstrap or any other framework included with OnsenUI?

Or can I use some custom CSS to do this?

Similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621239/how-do-i-center-a-button-between-two-other-buttons) but with OnsenUI and Monaca (so good for both ios and android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="toptoolbar">
  <button class="toolbar-button">
    <i class="fa fa-comments" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>
  <span class="stretcher"></span>
  <button class="toolbar-button">
    My title
    <!-- text-purple center-block doesn't work -->
  </button>
  <span class="stretcher"></span>
  <button class="toolbar-button pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#toptoolbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.stretcher {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: He wants only the second button to be in centre.
please correct if i am wrong .

Comment: my code will make the msg icon on left, My Title on center and 3 dots icon on right

Comment: : Oopppsss Sorry updated ur code at wrong place. It works.. Would have loved if you have given a fiddle . Copy pasting hurts :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// HTML

<div id="toptoolbar">
  <button class="toolbar-button">
    <i class="fa fa-comments" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>

  <button class="toolbar-button title">
    My title
    <!-- text-purple center-block doesn't work -->
  </button>

  <button class="toolbar-button pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" style="font-size:17px"></i>
  </button>
</div>

//CSS

.toolbar-button.title{
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
}
```

This is just a plain css solution.
updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2459/